# Using a JsonRequest to grab TeamCity User names: Internal

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, teamcity

My problem is that I have to somehow grab the username of the last person who built a select build.  With this information I would then place the username into a database.  Is this possible? Below is my Json call method.

```
      public JsonResult AllStatuses() //from the json called in the _client view
    {
        var buildStatuses = new List<BuildStatus>();
        var projects = Client.AllProjects();

        var user = Client.AllUsers();

        foreach (var project in projects)
        {                
            try 
            {
                var buildConfigs = Client.BuildConfigsByProjectId(project.Id);

                foreach (var buildConfig in buildConfigs)
                {
                    var b = new BuildStatus();
                    var build = Client.LastBuildByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id);
                    var status = Client.LastBuildByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id).Status; // Used to loop through BuildConfigID's to find which is a FAILURE, SUCCESS, ERROR, or UNKNOWN
                    b.user = user.ToString();

                    b.id = buildConfig.Id.ToString();

                    // If the date isn't null place the start date in long format
                    if (build.StartDate != null)
                        b.date = build.StartDate.ToString();

                    // If block; set the status based on the BuildconfigID from the var status
                    if (status.Contains("FAILURE")){
                        b.status = "FAILURE";
                    }
                    else if (status.Contains("SUCCESS")){
                        b.status = "SUCCESS";
                    }
                    else if (status.Contains("ERROR")){
                        b.status = "ERROR";
                    }
                    else{
                        b.status = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                    buildStatuses.Add(b);
                }

            } catch { }

        }
        var query = buildStatuses.OrderBy(x => x.status); // Create a sorted list from Error - Unknown               

        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail around "the last person who built a select build"? What kind of build trigger does the build have? If it is a vcs trigger it could be multiple people. If it is a manual trigger (clicking the button on the ui) it could be in a different place.

Comment: It is a manual trigger so the last one to press the run button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var change = Client.LastChangeDetailByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id); // Provides the changeID
                    var changeDetail = Client.ChangeDetailsByChangeId(change.Id); // Provides the username, this one populates the usernames
```

This is all I needed, the first var change found the change ID but did no populate the username field.  changeDetail with the new changeID found populates the username list.